# Reading json data from PHP back to ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have an ajax post function that gets data from the backend.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: action,
     result: "json",
     data: formData,
})
.done(function( msg ) {

    console.log(msg.status);

});
```

Php is

```
    return json_encode(array('status' => 'ok'));
```

But when i try to read msg.status the result is undefined. If I log msg value,it has: {"status":"ok"}

How do I read it in json format?

Comment: `return` in php doesn't perform output. Only output gets sent to the client as a response, therefore you must `echo` the json.

Comment: echo has the same result

Comment: then make sure no errors occur. if your code outputs/warnings, that'll corrupt the json. if your ajax call is expecting json, then ANY non-json output will corrupt the entire json response, even if the json portion is perfectly form. `Warning: blah blah at line 30{"status":"ok"}` is garbage as far as the json parser is concerned.

Comment: `result: 'json'`? You might want to glance over the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) You're looking for `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `result` property in `$.ajax`.  If you want to tell jQuery to parse the JSON for you, you need to use `dataType`.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: action,
     dataType: "json",
     data: formData,
})
.done(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg.status);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rocket, that worked! A thing that is confusing me a bit.. the data I am sending (formData) is not in json format, is not dataType supposed to be referring to the data argument of $.ajax instead of the return value?

Comment: @raphadko: No, `dataType` has nothing to do with the `data` property whatsoever.  `dataType` tells jQuery how to parse the *result*.  If you want to change the type of the *request*, you can use the `contentType` property.  See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/